# Can you transfer a .py file from windows to Linux via flash drive

Tags: linux, windows, python, file-transfer

I have been considering switching from windows to Linux sometime in the near future. But I do not want to lose or have to reprogram my python projects. Right now I am considering uploading said files onto a flash drive and transferring the files that way. Would this be a viable option or would there be a better way at going at this?

Comment: Yes, of course you can.  I would suggest Fat32 for the file system but Linux can read NTFS also.  Chances are that your flash drive is already good to go for transferring between the two OSs.   "Most" flavors of Linux will auto-mount your flash drive when you plug it in and you can copy the files over to your new Linux desktop or user home directory.

Comment: Side note: be aware of [different line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) in text files. Your `.py` files from Windows may use CRLF, in general Linux expects LF. AFAIK Python itself should not care, but text editors [may show you `^M`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001). `dos2unix` is the right tool to convert CRLF to LF. Additionally Linux expects all lines to be complete. I mean LF is a terminator, not a separator, so [the last line should end with LF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18743). AFAIK Python works with incomplete lines, but other tools may not.

Comment: *"But I do not want to lose or have to reprogram my python projects.*" -- Beyond line endings, there may be unavoidable differences between Python scripts designed on Windows and Linux. How many differences will probably depend on different factors, but you may still need to address simple things like folder path processing in certain instances (i.e. Windows uses C:\, while Linux uses /), even if no other changes are required.